# Nginx redirect that pass self as referrer

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to have Nginx do a redirect, but have the referrer set to it's own domain rather than the previous domain the client came from?

I know there is meta redirect, but it's slow. I also believe there's a php header redirect, but I have this rule and the php ends up being commented out in the page instead of executed:

```
location = /referrertest {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'origin';
    add_header Content-Type "text/html; charset=us-ascii";
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    return 200 "<?php header('Location: https://newsite.com'); exit(); ?>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't possible. It isn't nginx but the user browser who set the `Referer` header. Additional redirect from nginx would not change this header. But you can do something like this:

```
location = /referrertest {
    default_type text/html;
    return 200 "<head><script>window.location.assign('https://newsite.com/');</script></head>";
}
```

BTW what you tried to do can be done with `return 302 https://newsite.com/;` nginx directive.